# How can I isolate and then manipulate shapes in Python?

Tags: python, shapes, python-tesseract

I am working with a program called Pro Presenter. When this program starts up, I need to manually rearrange four blue boxes that represent projector screens, and they must be in a specific pattern for the program to work properly. Pro Presenter is unpredictable, and will sometimes scatter these boxes.

My goal is to write a Python script that can identify these boxes based on their vertical height so that my program can click and drag them into a specific pattern. Would pytesseract work for this purpose, or should I use a different library?

[image]

Comment: Use pyautogui locate function

Comment: Hi SmartManoj! Thank you for the advice! I'm sorry that I haven't written you until now; life has been crazy lately!

I'll try pyautogui locate!